# Is there a generic standard way to store floats in a std::set and/or a std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, stl, floating-point, nan

We know that NaN != NaN for IEEE floats. As a result, a number of "obvious" operations on floating pint numbers have a hidden gotchas in which NaNs in the data can mess things up terribly. For example:

- [Are IEEE floats valid key types for std::map and std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816156/are-ieee-floats-valid-key-types-for-stdmap-and-stdset)
- [Inserting multiple not-a-numbers into a std::unordered_set<double>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042495/inserting-multiple-not-a-numbers-into-a-stdunordered-setdouble)

The obvious approach is something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct NaNSafeEqual0 {
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const {
        if (!(a == a) || !(b == b)) {
            return (a == a) == (b == b); // <- Still has a gotcha: see below.
        }
        return a == b; // This deals with 0.0 == -0.0;
    }
};
```

This is complicated by the fact that `std::hash<float>` hashes bitwise values (in some implementations, at least), so for `std::unordered_set<float, std::hash<float>, ...>` we need our `KeyEqual` function to compare `KeyEqual()(NaN, NaN) == true` but `KeyEqual()(NaN, -NaN) == false`. For `std::unordered_set`, we can do bitwise comparison, except we still need `-0 == 0`.

I'm pretty sure I can write a robust (maybe not fast?) `NaNSafeLess<T>` and `NaNSafeEqual<T>`, but this sort of thing is notoriously tricky to get exactly right, and furthermore, it's tricky to make it generic. I think this is probably correct for the built-in POD types, although it's not fully generic 'cause it'll `static_assert` when `sizeof(T) > sizeof(std::size_t)`, and uses `union` in a dicy way.

```
template <typename T>
    struct NaNSafeEqual {
    std::size_t operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const {
        if (a == a || b == b) {
            return a == b; // At least one isn't nan.
        }
        static_assert(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(std::size_t));
        union {
            T data;
            std::size_t s;
        } ua, ub;
        ua.s = 0;
        ub.s = 0;
        ua.data = a;
        ub.data = b;
        return ua.s == ub.s;
    }
};
```

So: is there a generic standard way to write `less` and `equal` that allows safe storage of floats in a std::set and/or a std::unordered_set? If not, does Boost or some other widely-used library provide one?

Comment: When I say "generic" I mean, if there were a standard `NaNSafeEqual<T>` then I could specialize it for a `VecND<T, N>` type, so I could have `VecND<T, N>::operator==` have the typical NaN behavior but I could provide a specialized `NaNSafeEqual<VecND<T,N>>` that for two bitwise identical vectors of NaNs would evaluate as `true`.